# Blocked keys! How can I get emacs to see all keystrokes?

Tags: key-bindings, microsoft-windows

Windows 7 64-bit
emacs 27.1

Some keys of the form `C-M-<char>` evidently are not sent to Emacs.

How do I get them sent to Emacs?

Example:
Emacs does not respond `C-M-s`.

Also, does not show binding, i.e. no response to `C-h-c C-M-s`.  Instead, it waits for input into the minibuffer.

I have tried `(global-set-key [C-M-s] 'isearch-forward-regexp)`.  `C-M-s` remains invisible.

`C-h f` on `isearch-forward-regexp` shows it bound to `C-M-s`.

But some `C-M-<char>` keys work:

Partial list:

- `C-M-a`   not seen
- `C-M-b`   `backward-sexp` (global map)
- `C-M-c`   `exit-recursive-exit` (global map)
- `C-M-d`   not seen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are not binding the key correctly.  Use `(kbd "C-M-s")`, not `[C-M-s]`.
2. As for keys that Emacs never sees, because MS Windows intercepts it, you can try using `w32-register-hot-key`.  For example, this tells Windows to let Emacs use `M-<tab>`:

```lisp
(w32-register-hot-key [M-tab])
```

`C-h f w32-register-hot-key` says:

> **`w32-register-hot-key`** is a built-in function in `C source code`.
>
> `(w32-register-hot-key KEY)`
>
> Register `KEY` as a hot-key combination.
>
> Certain key combinations like `Alt-Tab` and `Win-R` are reserved for
> system use on Windows, and therefore are normally intercepted by the
> system.  These key combinations can be received by registering them
> as hot-keys, except for `Win-L` which always locks the computer.
>
> On Windows 98 and ME, `KEY` must be a one element key definition in
> vector form that would be acceptable to `define-key` (e.g. `[A-tab]` for
> `Alt-Tab`).  The `meta` modifier is interpreted as `Alt` if
> `w32-alt-is-meta` is `t`, and `hyper` is always interpreted as the Windows
> modifier keys.  The return value is the hotkey-id if registered, otherwise `nil`.
>
> On Windows versions since NT, KEY can also be specified as `[M-]`, `[s-]` or
> `[h-]` to indicate that all combinations of that key should be processed
> by Emacs instead of the operating system.  The super and hyper
> modifiers are interpreted according to the current values of
> `w32-lwindow-modifier` and `w32-rwindow-modifier`.  For instance,
> setting `w32-lwindow-modifier` to `super` and then calling
> `(register-hot-key [s-])` grabs all combinations of the left Windows
> key to Emacs, but leaves the right Windows key free for the operating
> system keyboard shortcuts.  The return value is `t` if the call affected
> any key combinations, otherwise `nil`.

Comment: Thanks!  The combination of kbd and w32-register-hot-key did the trick.